# Adding two tuples and applying a function to each element

Tags: python, tuples

I want to add a tuple (called pointer) to another tuple, then apply a clamp function I created to each of its elements, then finally return the new tuple.
I am sure there is a better way to do this:

```
from operator import add

pointer = (1, 1)
tuple2 = (1, 5)

pointer = map(add, pointer, tuple2)
x, y = pointer
x, y = clamp(x, 0, 3), clamp(y, 0, 3) # min = 0, max = 3
pointer = (x, y)
```

**[OUTPUT] pointer: (2, 3)**

Comment: what does add do in map?

Comment: provide full code and ask here: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I updated the code to include the import, it adds the elements of the tuples together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to create a clamping function with mixed limits, and then map that over the map object you get after the adding operation.

```
from operator import add
from functools import partial

def clamp(x, lo, hi):
    return max(lo, min(x, hi)) 

pointer = (1, 1)
tuple2 = (1, 5)
pointer = tuple(map(partial(clamp, lo=0, hi=3), map(add, pointer, tuple2)))
print(pointer)
```

**output**

```
(2, 3)
```

---

Another way would be to combine the adding and clamping into a single function. In the code below I use a function `make_add_clamp` which returns a function that does the adding and clamping using the limits passed to `make_add_clamp`.

```
from operator import add

def clamp(x, lo, hi):
    return max(lo, min(x, hi)) 

def make_add_clamp(lo, hi):
    def func(x, y):
        return clamp(x + y, lo, hi)
    return func

pointer = (1, 1)
tuple2 = (1, 5)

pointer = tuple(map(make_add_clamp(0, 3), pointer, tuple2))
print(pointer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can partially apply `clamp` manually:

```
>>> def clamp(a, m, M):
...   return min(max(a, m),M)
...
>>> clamp(2, 0, 3)
2
>>> clamp(6, 0, 3)
3
```

So define a new function...

```
>>> def clamp_partial(n):
...   return clamp(n,0,3)
...
```

And finally

```
>>> tuple(map(clamp_partial, map(add, pointer, tuple2)))
(2, 3)
>>>
```

Some people find comprehensions/generator expressions more readable, though. And there is no need to define a new function.

```
>>> pointer = (1, 1)
>>> tuple2 = (1, 5)
>>> pointer = (t1 + t2 for t1, t2 in zip(pointer, tuple2))
>>> pointer
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10218a780>
>>> pointer = tuple(clamp(p, 0, 3) for p in pointer)
>>> pointer
(2, 3)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use itertools.chain, The itertools.chain() method can be used to simplify this task. It takes a list of iterables as input, and returns an iterator that effectively masks the fact that you’re really acting on multiple containers. To illustrate, consider this example:

```
>>>from itertools import chain
>>>a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>b = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>>for x in chain(a, b):
...
 print(x)
...
1
2
3
4
x
y
z
```

Comment: In its current state your answer doesn't address the OP's question. You should show how `chain` can be applied to the OP's problem.